# How to create complicated layout in React Dashboard App

Tags: html, reactjs, user-interface, layout, webstorm

I am creating front end of Dashboard App using WebStorm IDE and React framework.

As I already created UI design, I want to continue with creating of layout. I want firstly create empty rectangles and then insert functions in them (not sure if it is the best workflow)

But there is a problem, that layout is a bit complicated, see picture:

[image: layout]

How should I proceed?

Should I use nested div tags and insert them into render function? Or there is other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I use nested div tags and insert them into render function?

Yes, that's exactly how you should proceed.

Use `css` to display them like you want. You can use front-end libraries to help you, like:

- [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/)
- [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

If you want to use bootstrap, you can have a look at [how to display the grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/).

You can also follow this tutorial from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to learn more about flexbox and how it works only with css (without material or bootstrap)

Comment: Is somewhere functional example?

Comment: @Tux I've added some links for examples and tutorials. Have a look, and please don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one if it helped with your question.